# Not able to perform operations on my database when the site is online

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'am doing a dynamic site in php. The contents to my 'project' page can be added/edited/deleted from the backend. I'm able to do the same from my computer (localhost). When I upload the site online, I'm not able to perform these operations. I have given all user privileges from the cpanel. Still its not working. I'm able to login to my backend and even view the contents that's been loaded dynamically. But i'm not able to add/delete/edit (only when its online). This is my connection code:

```html
<?php
$connection =mysql_connect("localhost","user_name","password");
$database=mysql_select_db("db_name");
if(isset($_SESSION["message1"]))
  {
   echo "<script language='javascript'> alert('{$_SESSION['message1']}'); </script>";
  }
?>
```

Can Somebody help me solve this? Is it something related to my host name?

Comment: mysql_* is depreciated , use mysqli_* instead of

Answer (score 1):

**I cannot add comments and that's why I answer your question !**

First check in your cPanel what PHP version you are using, if it's 7.x, you will not be able use mysql_* api, you may use mysqli_* or even better PDO, however, I think you can change your PHP version in cPanel to lower version, also if you can load contents with same connection using mysql_*, this might not be the problem !

Can you post your add/delete/edit queries here ?

- Your host should be probably ok, however you can test the connection using try {} catch {}

One thing that I can think of would be different table name or column name between your local and online database, this things might happen often when working on two different environments

Comment: php version of my cpanel is 5.6.Everything works like displaying data from database. But i'm not able to edit,delete or add anything.But these operations works in localhost..

Comment: i checked my table and column names.. Its all the same

Comment: <?php 
require_once("config/connection.php");
   session_start();
 $iduppid1=$_SESSION['cid'];

 $query5="delete from current_tb where cid={$iduppid1}";
 
    $resource=mysql_query($query5,$connection) ;
 {
  
 header("Location:currentview.php");
 }

?>